# How to create an active event (change BG or create border) on-click on AREA HREF tag?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I have one `div` and one `img` inside that DIV.
I have a map "area51" mapped in that `img` and a couple of `area` tags with link, the LEFT and the RIGHT.

Target Output: To be able to pop a yellow background color in the area being clicked or red border around the said area being hovered.

HTML:

```
<div class="LifestyleMoSub" width="320" height="120">
    <img width="320" height="120" class="LifestyleMoImg" src="http://placehold.it/300x200&text=mobile" border="0" usemap="#area51"/>
</div>

<!-- EDIT: added codes below -->    
<br />
<div class="emptyDiv"></div>
```

CSS:

```
area:hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

area:active {
    background-color: yellow;
}

/* EDIT: added codes below */
.emptyDiv {
    width: 320px; 
    height: 120px; 
    border: 1px solid red;    
}
.emptyDiv:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.emptyDiv:active {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.  CSS solution is very much preferred. Simple JS/JQuery can still be considered. Option for mobile on-tap is also nice to know. :)

https://jsfiddle.net/philcyb/b5coxcc3/3/

Comment: I wonder how is this related to [tag:android]

Comment: i mentioned about on-tap event. i was thinking that there might be a different code for that?

Comment: @Philcyb can you post more code? As i can't get your css class for class="LifestyleMoSub" and class="LifestyleMoImg" in the code you posted. Else, js fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) for the same would be the best

Comment: @Kailas - i have added a jsfiddle link to make my target output understandable. If you can open the fiddle and see the emptyDiv, that is how I want the LifestyleMoSub div to work.

Answer (score 0):

After thorough tests, I cannot implement to style area tag with css border or background-color.  So here's what I did as an alternative.  No map area tags. Just a simple img in a div that gives red border when hovered, and blue border when clicked.

HTML:

```
<div class="LifestyleMoSub" width="320" height="120">
    <a href="#">
        <img width="320" height="120" class="LifestyleMoImg" src="http://placehold.it/300x200&text=mobile" border="0"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.LifestyleMoSub {
    width: 320px; 
    height: 120px; 
}
.LifestyleMoSub:hover img {
    width: 318px; 
    height: 118px; 
    border: 1px solid red;    
}
.LifestyleMoSub:active img {
    width: 318px; 
    height: 118px; 
    border: 1px solid blue;    
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/philcyb/b5coxcc3/4/